# Correct and best way to structure a dynamic complex json

Tags: c#, json, struct

I need to obtain a complex json structured in this way:

```
Home1 -->|-->door1|--> doorname1
         |        |--> doorname2
         |-->door2 --> doorname1
         |        |--> doorname2
         |        |--> doorname3

Home2 -->|-->door1|--> doorname1
         |        |--> doorname2
         |-->door2 --> doorname1
         |        |--> doorname2
         |        |--> doorname3
         |-->door3 --> doorname1
         |        |--> doorname2
         |        |--> doorname3
         |        |--> doorname4
         |        |--> doorname5
```

And so on.. I don't know how many door an house can have and furthermore I don't know how many doornames a door can have. I suppose that I have to create a struct with struct inside it and as I said before I don't know how many doors an house can have I imagined that Home has to have a list of door and the struct door need to have a list of doorname.
As that said...what's the best way/approach to generate those structs?
this is what I have so far

```
public struct Json
{
    public List<Home> houses { get; set; }
}
public struct Home
{
    public List<Door> doors { get; set; }
} 
public struct Door
{
    public List<Doorname> doornames{ get; set; }
};
public struct Doorname
{
    public string names{ get; set; }
};
```

I not very sure (if not at all) if this is the right approach..I can't figure out how can I corectly preserve the connections between doornames with door and Home.
Can someone please point me in the right direction? Excuse me for the confusing question and the stupid example provided, I'm here to give a better explaination if needed.

Comment: What is the meaning of having `doorname` `struct` which is just a string?

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov should rapresent every name of the door

Comment: I mean why don't you just use string property?

Comment: Why call a `List<Home>` "houses" instead of "Homes"? Seems confusing naming (especially since usually not every Home is a House). Also shouldn't `doornames` just be called "Names", and be a `List<string>`? And why use `struct` instead of `class`? Also public properties should be `PascalCase` (begin with capital letter). Otherwise, the approach looks fine to me. If you have a Home that has a list of Names and you add it to a homes list, the connections are preserved. What problem are you encountering?